# Structuring labels

Tags: cross-referencing

I am currently writing my thesis and I am trying to properly structure the naming of labels. For instance, I use

```
\label{fig:abc:def:ghi}
```

for labeling a figure in my main chapter "abc", on some topic "def" with a certain name "ghi". I realize that this results in pretty long labels. On the other hand, I realize that I mostly reference figures only within a chapter.

Hence, I am wondering, how to simplify this.

Do you have suggestions on how I

- could automate adding the first part of the label (here: "fig") to the actual label based on the environment?
- could just use a reference to the type and the last part of the label (here: "fig:ghi") to reference things lying within my chapter and only have to use the long form ("fig:abc:def:ghi") if referencing outside the chapter

Comment: why do this at all? You only need to label figures that you reference, and you can just use `\label{my-cat}` if it's a picture of a cat. Why the complication of structured labels, given that the system does not use that structure and just uses it as a string?

Comment: auctex/reftex under emacs can already add/suggest such prefixes  automatically, see the variable `reftex-label-alist-entries` and `reftex-insert-label-flags`.  Which editor are you using?

Comment: Don't use extreme structured labels. If you move figure `fig:abc:def:ghi` from `def` to `xyz` you will go into trouble. BTW: Isn't this a primary option-based questions?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well for large documents creating a structure seems to make sense to me.

Comment: @Schweinebacke You are right, so I was looking for something to automate some parts of it for me.

Comment: @navige it is adding complication _for you_ (hence this question about how to control it) while making no difference at all to the system which does not treat `:` as special in any way inside a label string.

Comment: In case you use texstudio, you can automate the label creation, see https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#automatic-label-creation-by-pressing-wzxhzdk39-after-a-structure-command